# How to call the constructor on a std::queue<> that's in a structure that's already allocated

Tags: c++

Assuming I have a structure that is of unknown origin (could be stack, could be heap, etc), could be just pointing to an allocated buffer in memory:

```
  struct QueueData{
    HANDLE hSemaphore;
    HANDLE hMutex;
    std::queue<void*> m_queue;
  };
```

And it is handed to me, how do I call the constructor on the queue so that it's internal members are appropriately initialized?

```
QueueData *pData = (QueueData*)pPreAllocatedMemoryThatsBigEnoughToHoldQueueData;
pData->m_queue = std::queue<void*>();
```

Doesn't work.  I'm assuming a validly formed std::queue is being created on the stack, but the assignment fails because the instance in my structure has unknown data in it.

I tried for a while to try to find a way to explicitly call the constructor, but couldn't.

I ended up do an in-place new on pData:

```
pData = new (pData) QueueData();
```

to get it to call the constructor.

What is the right syntax to initialize a std:queue<> that's already been preallocated?

(And please, I understand I'm tempting the gods of UB, but the underlying code is doing this as a mock of an RTOS using windows API calls and keeping the underlying data structures hidden and do as few internal allocs as possible)

Comment: The _placement new_ that you're using is the way to do it.  You could simplify a bit and go with `QueueData *pData = new (pPreAllocatedMemoryThatsBigEnoughToHoldQueueData) QueueData();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is how you do it. Not only for `std::queue<>` but for any object you want to construct on a preallocated buffer.

In your case, since the `std::queue<>` is part of a struct, constructing a `QueueData` object this way will ensure its member `m_queue` is constructed as well. Bear in mind this constructor may allocate memory.

Don't forget to call the destructor explicitly before deallocating the buffer, otherwise you'll leak the memory allocated on the constructor, or during the normal operation of the `std::queue`. E.g:

```
pData->~QueueData();
somethingThatDeallocatesTheBuffer(pData);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it directly to the std::queue<> rather than the struct that contains it?  (I suppose that was really my question.  wanting to avoid the indiredction)

Comment: Technically that would be wrong, as the other fields of the structure would be uninitialized. You can do `new (&pdata->m_queue) std::queue<void*>;`, but what you have now is better.

Comment: The code generated by the compiler on both versions will probably be identical, so I am not sure what is the "indirection" you are talking about, but constructing the whole struct is semantically more correct (imagine in the future you add an `std::vector` to the struct, in the first version you are already covered).

Comment: @ivella thanks for that.  Yes, in retrospect the right thing to do is "construct' the structure and destruct it on my object's delete function.